# Resolving Reference Error with call-back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, snap.svg

I've been hitting wall after wall while following along with almost all of the basic snap.svg tutorials out there. While running their code through [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sasquiche/3kLrwvgm/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/roblevin/pen/OPBQmd) everything works, but when I try the same through my own local editor I've had little luck.

My code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/snap.svg.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="svg" class="svg"></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var surface = Snap("#svg");
var circ = surface.circle(100, 100, 50);
circ.attr({
    fill: "#addedd",
    strokeWidth: 10,
    stroke: "#beeeef"
});
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

The main issue I was always presented was a Reference Error for the line:

```
var surface = Snap("#svg");
```

I resolved this by including a callback and wrapping the block in a function:

```
function main(){
var surface = Snap("#svg");
var circ = surface.circle(100, 100, 50);
circ.attr({
    fill: "#addedd",
    strokeWidth: 10,
    stroke: "#beeeef"
 });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

I feel like these tutorials are skipping something? I'm sure there is a better resolution than what I came up with? What do you think?

I just want to start learning Snap!

Comment: Download jquery locally first

Comment: @Amit Downloaded jquery locally and updated the HTML. No change to the original or my resolution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, Snap code can only be executed once, jQuery is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var surface = Snap("#svg");
    var circ = surface.circle(100, 100, 50);
    circ.attr({
        fill: "#addedd",
        strokeWidth: 10,
        stroke: "#beeeef"
    });
});
```

The order of loading js files is important. <strike>Since snap has a dependency on jQuery, you can't execute it until jQuery is ready</strike>.

More than Snap or any javaScript library, it is important for you to understand the basic of JS first. Smaller files will be loaded faster than a large file even though, they are requested afterwards.

In your case, even before jQuery got downloaded, main function of your js got executed and you got an error. This is why, $(document).ready is always the preferred way of starting your code with jQuery.

**EDIT**:

As @Ian has pointed out, snap has no dependency on jQuery. The actual issue was of the wrong ordering of the js files. The correct order should be as the following,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/snap.svg.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="svg" class="svg"></svg>

    <!-- custom code should be loaded after the svg markup -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This cleaned up my method very well! What do you typically do when copying code from jsfiddle and codepen to your local library? Being new it's a bit hard to learn coding from examples on the web then moving them to local.

Comment: @Vili it's important to look for some documentation before getting started. Like in this case, you thought that the issue was with Snap however, this was because of jQuery. Similarly, most of these libr usually have a callback to let you know when they are ready for use. You can rely upon them as a starting point of your code execution. Finally, you learn from your mistakes. There will always be errors. You fix them and you have learned something new in the process :)

Comment: Snap has no dependency on Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Snap has no dependency on jquery.

The problem may be that you are running the script and calling this line.

```
var surface = Snap("#svg");
```

Before the svg markup

```
<svg id="svg" class="svg"></svg>
```

is loaded into the DOM. So it can't find the element to reference. The issue isn't related to Snap at all, just normal HTML/SVG and JS loading and ordering.

What isn't clear from the original code, is when you are loading your own js code in. You could try putting it after the svg markup, but generally it's preferred to make sure the document is ready first with...

```
$(document).ready( ... )
```

As you have already found :).

Comment: That was the actual issue.

Comment: @ian I saw your answer got snatched, I wanted to thank you for adding more clarification to my problem!

Comment: No problem, main thing is as long as you understand in the end!